# Contradiction on an Inequality

Tags: inequality, summation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method

The problem on which I have a problem is this-

> Let a, b, c be non-negative real numbers. Prove that $$ \sum_{cyc} {a^2-bc \over 2a^2+b^2+c^2} \ge 0 $$

While solving and after some resolution, we get $$ \sum_{cyc} {(a+b)^2 \over a^2+b^2+2c^2} \le 3 $$
And by C-S, we have,
$$ \sum_{cyc} {(a+b)^2 \over a^2+b^2+2c^2} \le \sum_{cyc} {2(a^2+b^2) \over a^2+b^2+2c^2} $$
It rests to prove that
$$ \sum_{cyc} {a^2+b^2 \over a^2+b^2+2c^2} \le {3 \over 2} $$
By cyclic substitutions of $x$ for $b^2+c^2$, we get,
$$ \sum_{cyc} {a^2+b^2 \over a^2+b^2+2c^2} = \sum_{cyc} {(a^2+b^2) \over (c^2+a^2)+(b^2+c^2)} = \sum_{cyc} {z \over x+y} \le {3 \over 2} $$
But by the **Nesbitt's Inequality**,
$$ \sum_{cyc} {z \over x+y} \ge {3 \over 2} !$$
Can anybody explain me where's the mistake and the correction?
Thanks!

Comment: Your original approach seems to loose too much i.e. the inequalities are not sharp enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution.

By your work we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a+b)^2}{a^2+b^2+2c^2}\leq3,$$ which is true by C-S:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a+b)^2}{a^2+b^2+2c^2}\leq\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2}{a^2+c^2}+\frac{b^2}{b^2+c^2}\right)=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2}{a^2+c^2}+\frac{c^2}{c^2+a^2}\right)=3.$$

Answer (score 2):

Your first step was not so strong, which gave a wrong inequality.

SOS helps here:

We need to prove that $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)(a+c)-(c-a)(a+b)}{2a^2+b^2+c^2}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)\left(\frac{a+c}{2a^2+b^2+c^2}-\frac{b+c}{2b^2+a^2+c^2}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(c^2-(a+b)c+a^2-ab+b^2)(2c^2+a^2+b^2)\geq0,$$ which is true because $$c^2-(a+b)c+a^2-ab+b^2\geq c^2-(a+b)c+\frac{1}{4}(a+b)^2=\frac{1}{4}(2c-a-b)^2\geq0.$$

Comment: Is there an easier proof? And what is SOS?

Comment: @Book Of Flames I see also five ways to the proof. This way is an easiest. SOS it's Sum Of Squares method. How it works, you saw already.

Comment: Anyways I have an easier proof in my book. Thanks!

Comment: @Book Of Flames If you know a proof of this inequality, why do you ask the question?

Comment: I was thinking to get a for a way out through my approach. But I know that it is wrong, so I was asking for an improvement/correction. But Thanks a lot.